# How to add one more editor for pages /post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hello Friends 
 I want to add one more editor for wordpress pages/post .Is there is any plugin or any thing .Please let me know if any one having any idea about this.I shall be very thank ful to you

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use a different editor for posts/pages than the built in one?  I haven't tried this one but it looks good and I've been meaning to try it:

http://www.deanlee.cn/wordpress/fckeditor-for-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: No I need two editor in admin.I don't want flavor of editor .My mean is that in wordpress we have one editor box.My content cant managble through one editor bcoz html little bit complicated .I want one more edtior just below the previous one editor.I need to paste half html in one editor and other half html in second editor.Hope now its clear what actually I want.Thanks for reply

Comment: I haven't seen anything like that nor can I imagine any circumstances under which you would need it.  The way wordpress works, the content of your post/page can't be split so having two editors each with half the content wouldn't really make sense.  Perhaps you are looking for an editor that can be split vertically so you can see the top and bottom of the content at the same time?  I don't see anything that allows you to do this (from a quick google search).

Comment: I have used something like before 10 month ago.But due to my system corrupt I lost that.And now I dont figure out any help but trust its possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for multiple VISUAL/HTML editors (to control different parts of your post/page), you can either use custom fields or a plugin called PODS CMS.

If you are using custom fields, read:

codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

A very popular plugin that works with custom fields is FLUTTER. I haven't used it myself, but I have used other plugins and I would probably go with Flutter because of what I have heard about it.

If you use PODS CMS, be aware that it doesn't work with plugins that require custom fields (for example, many feature slider plugins) but it's a great way to have multiple text fields on the same page. It's great for very customized content.

PODS CMS does require some php knowledge but the documentation online is very good:

mondaybynoon.com/2010/01/04/introduction-to-pods-cms-wordpress/

Personally, if I have more than one custom field per post/page, I would go with PODS, but that is just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of above question.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-content-blocks/

Using this you can easily add one more editor for page or posts

Thanks